# How draw variable background in day cell?

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I'm looking for a way (short of a background image) to set calendar day background to several colored bands.  For instance, the 17th might need to half the top half light blue and the bottom half light yellow.  Or the day background might be split into 3 or 4 horizontal bands, with each day being different.  Any ideas using CSS?

If not, what is the property method for setting a specific day's background image in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Custom CSS gradients, if you can rely on modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do anything with javascript. You could simply edit the CSS for the "today" cell.

```
.fc-state-highlight {
    background: #ffc;
}
```

This will fix it. Also, I would look into using CSS gradients also.  http://gradients.glrzad.com/

If you want to change the javascript, since FullCalendar uses jQuery. You could write a function to interact with the date and make it random. I'm not quite sure if I could think of it right now. Ideally, have it add a class to each day.

```
$('.fc-state-highlight').css({"background":"GRADIENT"});
```

However, for now. I'd recommend using the functions on http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/